# Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging"

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I'm trying to run flutter on iOS Simulator and when executing `flutter run` the next error appears:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
> In Podfile:
> firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 9.1.3, which depends on
> Firebase/Messaging (= 7.11.0)
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Messaging (= 7.11.0)`.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

**What if tried:**

1. Flutter clean + flutter pug get
2. Delete de iOS folder and then `flutter create .`
3. On the iOS folder delete `Pods` file and `Podfile.dock` then `pod init` + `pod install` causing same error

**The packages i'm using**

- cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
- cross_connectivity: ^3.0.2
- crypto: ^3.0.1
- device_info_plus: ^1.0.1
- encrypt: ^5.0.0
- firebase_analytics: ^8.0.2
- firebase_core: ^1.1.0
- firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.2
- firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
- flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
- flutter_card_swipper: ^0.4.0
- flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
- flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+1
- flutter_speed_dial: ^3.0.5
- fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
- http: ^0.13.2
- image: ^3.0.2
- image_picker: ^0.7.4
- intl: ^0.17.0
- location: ^4.1.1
- mime_type: ^1.0.0
- path_provider: ^2.0.1
- permission_handler: ^6.1.3
- shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
- sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
- url_launcher: ^6.0.3
- webview_flutter: ^2.0.4

**Configuartion**

- iOs Deployment Target 12.1
- Flutter 2.0.4
- `flutter doctor -v` Result -> all green colored

I preferred to ask here before creating a new issue on [Github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/new)
If this is happening to someone else then I'll create a new issue on Github.

Comment: did you try pod update inside iOS folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem can occur when using a Mac with the M1 chip.

The '[CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5984)' error wil be solved when solving first the '[pod repo update](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5984#issuecomment-830043981)' error.

I've tried different solutions but the ones that worked for me was the following.
Steps to follow:

1. On the terminal run: `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
2. On the ios project folder run: `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update` instead of `pod repo update` (just in case delete the Podfile.lock before this step)
3. Now your build should be successful, press F5.

Ther are more solutions mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10541#issuecomment-807915349).

I finally found mine on this [comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10518#issuecomment-830134956).

Comment: It's worked for me clearly

Answer (score 4):

you should update the cocoa master repos with

```
pod repo update
```

then

```
pod install
```

again

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve similar error by updating the target iOS platform to `10.0`. Update the platform configured in the Podfile to `platform :ios, '10.0'`. I've also had to update the iOS Deployment Target to 10.0 - located on `Runner > Info > Deployment Target`

[image: Xcode iOS Deployment Target]

After that, deleting the Podfile.lock with `rm -rf Podfile.lock` then running `pod update` and `pod install` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
pod update Firebase/Messaging
```

fixed me up

Answer (score 0):

don't specify firebase_messaging version

```yaml
firebase_messaging: // remove version from here
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of pod repo update

> arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```yaml
firebase_core: null
firebase_crashlytics: null
firebase_messaging: null
```

Comment: event after doing the cleaning steps again:
- Flutter clean + flutter pug get
- Delete de iOS folder and then flutter create .
- On the iOS folder delete Pods file and Podfile.dock then pod init + pod install

Comment: Even after that. Seems like the problem its caused by 'missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle - '. This error can be seen when running `pod repo update` on the iOs folder. I'm still looking for a solution on this. We'll know if the first problem is solved after solving the 'pod repo update' error.