# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessaging":

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, cocoapods, apple-m1

Error running Flutter app on iOS after upgrading dependencies in pub.dev. (M1 mac)
The app runs smoothly on android devices.
**Debug console:**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
    firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_in_app_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_in_app_messaging/ios`
    firebase_in_app_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
.
.
.


    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
.
.
.

performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessaging":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_in_app_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_in_app_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 0.7.4-12, which depends on
          Firebase/InAppMessaging (= 10.20.0)

    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/InAppMessaging (= 10.20.0)`.

    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-.
.
.
.


Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.


Exited (1).
```

Tried everything from deleting pods to cleaning pub cache, but the issue is still here.

```
hamza@Hamzas-macbook ios % arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update --allow-root
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_in_app_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessaging":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_in_app_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_in_app_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 0.7.4-12, which depends on
      Firebase/InAppMessaging (= 10.20.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/InAppMessaging (= 10.20.0)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

**Commands I have already tried (after deleting pods):**

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
flutter pub get
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
arch -x86_64 pod install

**Dependencies:**

firebase_auth: ^4.15.3
firebase_core: ^2.24.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
firebase_database: ^10.4.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.10
firebase_analytics: ^10.8.0
firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.7.4+12

```
hamza@Hamzas-macbook ios % flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies in ..... (15.0s)
  ffi 2.1.0 (2.1.2 available)
> file 7.0.0 (was 6.1.4)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.0 available)
  matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.2 available)
Changed 1 dependency in ..!
8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
hamza@Hamzas-macbook ios % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.7, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64,
    locale en-PK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
hamza@Hamzas-macbook
```

**Pod file**

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
.
.
.


target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete **podfile.lock** first and in terminal try this commands.

```
pod deintegrate
pod install --repo-update
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Already tried  this so many times but still not working

Comment: Then please checkout this answer it might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67365250/19807154

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything finally I found the solution.

1. **Update Flutter**
2. **Update Cocoapods**
3. **Update Xcode**
4. **Flutter clean**
5. **pod deintegrate**
6. **Flutter pub get**
7. **arch -x86_64 pod install**
8. **Flutter run**

basically, you have to update everything to the latest version to the latest version to resolve the compatibility issue.